# Delete white background of image

Tags: css

I was wondering how I would delete the white space that is presented in this photo in css or html. I want the background to be transparent. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRlE9.png

This is the code I used :

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./StyleSheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="./Images/Abado.png">
    </div>
    <div class="Navbar"> 
    <a href= "index.php">Home</a>
    <a href= "#">About us</a>
    <a href="#">Forums</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <a href= "Signup.php">Signup</a> 
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>


body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


img{
    height: 50px;
    background-color:transparent;
}

#header{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
background:#124EF4;
height: auto;   
}

.Navbar{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left; 
    background: #0033BF;
}

.Navbar a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 18px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS and create a demo of your output.

Comment: use something like photoshop to do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  read it and improve your question. This is a candidate to be closed.

Comment: If the image doesn't have transparency it can't be added by CSS. *Maybe* Javascript but the results might be unexpected. Just use am image editor and remove the white in that.

Comment: CSS would not be the right choice for your solution. Use an advanced image editor like www.gimp.org which is free and refer to think link on how to do the transparency http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent-in-gimp

Answer (score 1):

You can use photoshop or any other image editor program to make your images transparent. In photoshop, you can select the magic eraser tool and delete the white background, and save the photo as in png format.